# ServerXMLHTTP/WinHTTPRequest Certificate Chain Issued by Untrusted Authority

Tags: ssl, vbscript, winhttp, winhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I am attempting to execute a request using the following:

```
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") 'Was initially trying ServerXMLHTTP here
httpRequest.Open "POST", "<WSDL Endpoint Here>", False
httpRequest.Send payload
```

Instead, an error ("The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted." / 80090325) is being returned regardless of what I try.

Navigating to the WSDL in a web browser works fine and requests executed through SoapUI also succeed.

I have attempted to ignore server errors using the following but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have also tried different versions of the ServerXMLHTTP object.

```
httpRequest.setOption 2, 13056
```

The chain of the certificate for the WSDL looks like [Company Root CA 1] > [Company Issuing CA 1] > [Cert for WSDL Site] and I have confirmed that the Company Root CA 1 certificate is installed under Trusted Root Certification Authorities for the Local Computer account.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55100318/692942) a few years ago never got an answer.

Comment: WinHTTP (winhttpcom.dll) -vs- ServerXMLHTTP (msxml3.dll/msxml6.dll) use different options.  Try `.SetOption 4, 13056` for WinHTTP.  For reference, [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequestoption).  Also, be wary of secure redirects, CRL/OCSP checks, proxy auth/error pages, account contexts, etc.  Sometimes, temporarily enabling `Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > CAPI2 > Operational` event logging (in eventvwr.msc) can reveal some good insights.